# How to fix ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

when I build my experiment model using `tf.kears.layer` functional API, I got GraphDisconnected Error as follow:

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last)
>
> in ()
> 35 outputs = x
> 36
> ---> 37 model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
> 38 model.summary()
>
> 4 frames
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py
> in _map_graph_network(inputs, outputs)
> 988                              'The following previous layers '
> 989                              'were accessed without issue: ' +
> --> 990                              str(layers_with_complete_input))
> 991         for x in nest.flatten(node.outputs):
> 992           computable_tensors.add(id(x))
>
> ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor
> Tensor("input_63:0", shape=(?, 32, 32, 32), dtype=float32) at layer
> "tf_op_layer_Pow_105". The following previous layers were accessed
> without issue: []

to understand this error, I looked into possible SO post but not able to remove the error. I think it is because of shape mismatching at some layers. I double-checked the shape of each layer but the error still persists. I am not sure what caused the problem. Can anyone suggest a possible idea of solving this error? any quick solution to fix this?

**update: my full coding attempt**:

```
def my_func(x):
    n = 2
    c = tf.constant([1, -1/6], dtype=tf.float32)
    p = tf.constant([1,3], dtype=tf.float32)
    W,H, C = x.shape[1:].as_list()
    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(W,H,C))
    xx = inputs
    res = []
    for i in range(n):
        m = c[i] * tf.math.pow(xx, p[i])
        res.append(m)
    csum = tf.math.cumsum(res)
    csum_tr = tf.transpose(csum, perm=[1, 2, 3, 4, 0])
    new_x = tf.reshape(csum_tr, tf.constant([-1, W, H, C*n]))
    return new_x

inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(32,32,3))

conv_1 = Conv2D(64, kernel_size = (3, 3), padding='same')(inputs)
BN_1 = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(conv_1)
pool_1 = MaxPooling2D(strides=(1,1), pool_size=(3,3), padding='same')(BN_1)
z0 = my_func(pool_1)

conv_2 = Conv2D(64, kernel_size = (3, 3), padding='same')(z0)
BN_2 = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(conv_2)
pool_2 = MaxPooling2D(strides=(1,1), pool_size=(3,3), padding='same')(BN_2)
z1 = my_func(pool_2)
merged_2 = concatenate([z0, z1], axis=-1)
act_2 = Activation('tanh')(merged_2)

x = Conv2D(64, kernel_size = (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(act_2)
x = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3))(x)
x = Dropout(0.1)(x)

x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(128)(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation('tanh')(x)
x = Dropout(0.1)(x)

x = Dense(10)(x)
x = Activation('softmax')(x)
outputs = x

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
model.summary()
```

can anyone point me out what causes the problem? how should I fix the graph disconnected error above? any quick thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the correct way to write your custom function... there is no need to use an additional `Input` layer

```
def my_func(x):
    
    n = 2
    c = tf.constant([1, -1/6], dtype=tf.float32)
    p = tf.constant([1,3], dtype=tf.float32)
    W, H, C = x.shape[1:].as_list()

    res = []
    for i in range(n):
        m = c[i] * tf.math.pow(x, p[i])
        res.append(m)
    
    csum = tf.math.cumsum(res)
    csum_tr = tf.transpose(csum, perm=[1, 2, 3, 4, 0])
    new_x = tf.reshape(csum_tr, tf.constant([-1, W, H, C*n]))
    
    return new_x
```

you can apply it inside your network simple using a `Lambda` layer

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(32,32,3))

conv_1 = Conv2D(64, kernel_size = (3, 3), padding='same')(inputs)
BN_1 = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(conv_1)
pool_1 = MaxPooling2D(strides=(1,1), pool_size=(3,3), padding='same')(BN_1)
z0 = Lambda(my_func)(pool_1)  ## <=================

conv_2 = Conv2D(64, kernel_size = (3, 3), padding='same')(z0)
BN_2 = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(conv_2)
pool_2 = MaxPooling2D(strides=(1,1), pool_size=(3,3), padding='same')(BN_2)
z1 = Lambda(my_func)(pool_2)  ## <=================
merged_2 = concatenate([z0, z1], axis=-1)
act_2 = Activation('tanh')(merged_2)

x = Conv2D(64, kernel_size = (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(act_2)
x = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3))(x)
x = Dropout(0.1)(x)

x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(128)(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation('tanh')(x)
x = Dropout(0.1)(x)

x = Dense(10)(x)
x = Activation('softmax')(x)
outputs = x

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
model.summary()
```